# Given Players participating in Games, rank Player Combination based on total score change

Tags: sql

Players combine into what I call *squads* to play in games. They are joined to the Games table via the Lineup table. The number of players in a squad can vary from 1-5. I would like to create a leaderboard ranking the squads, but this query is beyond me.

- I'd like to exclude 1-player squads
- I don't have a strong opinion on the criteria for ranking, but the best I've come up with so far is a sum of the `elo_change` field. Players on a losing squad will all get a negative `elo_change`, and players on a winning squad get a positive change. If a ranking based on other criteria such as number of wins is easier, that'd be okay.

**EDIT** Also, I am able to make changes to this schema if it makes a query possible. FWIW my current backend is sqlite and if I move to something more powerful it will probably be postgresql.

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "team" (
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "teamname" varchar(255) NOT NULL COLLATE nocase
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "game" (
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "winner_id" integer,
  "loser_id" integer,
  "home_team_id" integer NOT NULL,
  "away_team_id" integer NOT NULL,
  "team_size" integer NOT NULL,
  "is_completed" integer NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" datetime NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ("winner_id") REFERENCES "team" ("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("loser_id") REFERENCES "team" ("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("home_team_id") REFERENCES "team" ("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("away_team_id") REFERENCES "team" ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "player" (
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL COLLATE nocase,
  "elo" integer NOT NULL,
  "team_id" integer,
  FOREIGN KEY ("team_id") REFERENCES "team" ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "lineup" (
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "game_id" integer NOT NULL,
  "player_id" integer NOT NULL,
  "team_id" integer NOT NULL,
  "elo_change" integer NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ("game_id") REFERENCES "game" ("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("player_id") REFERENCES "player" ("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("team_id") REFERENCES "team" ("id")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a "squad" a "team" in your datamodel? If so would it suffice if you count the wins and losses? Below "pseudo" mysql query totals up the wins and losses of a team (The syntax may vary depending on the database you're using).

```
select team.teamname, 
       sum(CASE WHEN team.id = game.winner_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wins, 
       sum(CASE WHEN team.id = game.loser_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as losses
   from team, game
where (team.id = game.winner_id or team.id = game.loser_id)
  and game.is_completed = 1
  and game.team_size > 1
group by team.teamname
order by wins desc, losses asc
```

Comment: No, squad != team. Think of it like trying to rank what starting lineup of an NBA team correlates with the most victories for that team. In this case the lineup/squad matters more than what team they belong to, and ideally I'm interested in their total elo_change

Comment: I'm not too much into sports stats but it sounds a little like a squad table is needed that has e.g. an id, squadname, teamid. The players can be related to a squad via a squad_player many to many table with squadid, playerid. A squad can be assicated to a game through a squad_game many to many table (or alternatively you can add the winner&looser squadid to the game table). With that you coud capture the lineup for each game. Would that possibly help?

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing this or how it would get me closer. Squad ID, Squad Name, and Squad.TeamID are not information I need (they are not named and squads can and will change teams frequently. Player A and B may play together several games on Team 1, and then play together on Team 2). The squad is the combination of Player A and B.
As far as I can tell all the data I need is captured in the Lineup table, I just can't figure out how to get at it in this way.